# JavaScript add new row and populate new rows inputs with data from dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I hope you can help me with a Javascript problem I'm having, I've been staring at this for days and I just can't figure it out!!

I've got a script that splits the value of an option dropdown and populates certain feilds with the splitted values.

Then I've got an 'Add Order Line' hyperlink to add a new row to a table, but I want the above feature to happen on any new line as well but nothing happens

I've recreated this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dPX2/15/).

```
$(window).load(function(){
var selectEl = document.getElementById('part_selection');
selectEl.onchange = function () {
    //var input1 = document.getElementsByName('PART_NO');
    var input2 = document.getElementById('PART_DESCRIPTION');
    var input3 = document.getElementById('PART_PRICE');
    var input4 = document.getElementById('UNIT_MEAS');
    var val = this.value;
    var parts = val.split("_");
    /*input1.value = parts[0];*/
    input2.value = parts[1];
    input3.value = parts[2];
    input4.value = parts[3];
}
});
$(function(){
    var counter = 1;

    $('a.add-line').on('click',function()
    {
        counter ++;
        $(this).prev('table.orderlinelist').find('tr').last().clone().find('input').val('').end().find('input.ORDER_LINE_NO').val(counter).end().appendTo('table.orderlinelist');
    });
    });

<table class="orderlinelist">
<tr>
    <td>Line</td>
    <td>Part</td>
    <td>Part Description</td>
    <td>Unit Price</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>UoM</td>
    <td>Line Total</td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="ORDER_LINE_NO[]" class="ORDER_LINE_NO" id="ORDER_LINE_NO" value="1" readonly="readonly"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="PART_NO" id="part_selection">
            <option value="">Select a Part</option>         
            <option class="dropdown1" value="5461_Coxmoor Sideboard_299.00_EACH">5461</option>  
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="part_desc" id="PART_DESCRIPTION" readonly />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="PART_PRICE[]" id="PART_PRICE" class="orderprice"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="QTY[]" id="QTY" class="orderqty"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="UNIT_MEAS[]" id="UNIT_MEAS" class="orderuom"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="TOTAL" id="TOTAL" class="orderprice"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<a href="#" title="" class="add-line">Add Line</a>
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Comment: First of all stop working with id's when you're adding rows, id's are meant to be unique and used once, when you're duplicating rows you'll have multiple equal id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are steps you can take to do what you want:

1. first add `class` attributes to the `input` tags, instead of `ID`.
2. Use jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to handle your dynamic event.
3. Use `closest` to find the current row.
4. then using jQuery `find`, find the inputs based on their `class` attributes.

And continue the rest of your code scenario.

---

I took these steps on your code like:

```
$(document).on("change", "table.orderlinelist .part_selection", function () {
    var jrow = $(this).closest('tr');
    var input2 = jrow.find('.PART_DESCRIPTION');
    var input3 = jrow.find('.PART_PRICE');
    var input4 = jrow.find('.UNIT_MEAS');
    var val = this.value;
    var parts = val.split("_");
    input2.val(parts[1]);
    input3.val(parts[2]);
    input4.val(parts[3]);
});
```

This is your working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dPX2/20/)

Answer (score 0):

you are duplicating the identifiers of elements and assigning this event change the "select" Specific.
yours is better to work with classes in this way

http://jsfiddle.net/4dPX2/16/

```
$(".orderlinelist").on("change", ".part_selection", function (e) {});
```